# Kendo checkbox toggle true and false states not working properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get it so when one or more checkbox is clicked, I'm able to get a button to appear. I would like the toggle function to work if one or more checkbox is clicked, but instead, it will turn on when I select one checkbox, then turn off during the next selection. I'm sure I've got a couple of unnecessary properties added into here as well, but not too concerned about that. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML: Button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
*ngIf="switchCase" style="float:right"
>Save</button>
```

HTML: Checkbox Column

```
<kendo-grid-column field="checkbox" editor="boolean">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem id="flexSwitchCheckChecked"
    >
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleButton(dataItem, 'checkbox' 
    [checked]="dataItem.checkbox"
    [width]="40"
      >
```

TS: Button click method

```
public switchCase: boolean = false;
  toggleButton() {
    this.switchCase = !this.switchCase;
```

Answer (score 1):

pass an event to your function then access its value from typescript class:
Step1(pass an $event):
on *ngFor tag level add an index var

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index" >
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleButton($event,i)">
</div>
```

Step1(get its value):

```
      toggleButton($event,i) {
    let newValue = $event.target.value;
       // this.switchCase =newValue;

this.items[i].checked =  newValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting the error:  (parameter) $event: any
Parameter '$event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006
}

How do I fix that issue?

Comment: $events:any on ts file

Comment: Sorry instead of click write input

Comment: thank you. the console values for the switch case seem to be the same whether I am checking or unchecking the box, is there a way to fix this so when there are no boxes checked, the button dissapears?

Comment: use change instead of click

Comment: <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleButton($event)">

Comment: still not making a difference for some odd reason, but I do really appreciate your helping me!

Comment: I think We need more explanation from your part to solve this issue.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you for your patience. 

For the TS method I've got:
  public switchCase: boolean = false;
  toggleButton($event: any) {
    let newValue = $event;
    this.switchCase =newValue;
    console.log(this.switchCase)

and for the html I now have: 
   <kendo-grid-column field="checkbox" editor="boolean">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem id="flexSwitchCheckChecked">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleButton($event)">
    </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

Comment: Unfortunately, the way it is now, it does not toggle the button "off" when deselecting a checkbox. It stays on whether I select or DE-select a checkbox.

Comment: on your ts file get the index of your toggled item then change your items array to fit the new state . I will change my code . wait a few minutes

Comment: Sorry I have been confused between ionic angular . instead of      $event.details.value  use  $event.target.value